# Pandas Dataframe to DMatrix

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, xgboost

I am trying to run xgboost in scikit learn.  And I am only using Pandas to load the data into a dataframe. How am I supposed to use pandas df with xgboost?  I am confused by the DMatrix routine required to run the xgboost algorithm.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the dataframe's `.values` method to access raw data once you have manipulated the columns as you need them.

E.g.

```
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
target = train['target']
train = train.drop(['ID','target'],axis=1)
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
test = test.drop(['ID'],axis=1)

xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train.values, target.values)
xgtest = xgb.DMatrix(test.values)
```

Obviously you may need to change which columns you drop or use as the training target. The above was for a Kaggle competition, so there was no target data for `xgtest` (it is held back by the organisers).

Comment: When trying this way `xgb.DMatrix(X_train.values, y_train.values)` I am seeing `TypeError: can not initialize DMatrix from dict`

Comment: @javadba: It definitely worked in 2016 on my mcahine! I cannot test this at the moment as I cannot install xgboost. It is possible some library code has changed. More likely there is something different about your situation. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402461/xgboost-typeerror-can-not-initialize-dmatrix-from-dataframe but that simply advises you to do exactly what this answer does (i.e. use `.values`)

Answer (score 12):

You can now use Pandas DataFrames directly with XGBoost. Definitely works with xgboost 0.81.

For example where X_train, X_val, y_train, and y_val are DataFrames:

```
import xgboost as xgb

mod = xgb.XGBRegressor(
    gamma=1,                 
    learning_rate=0.01,
    max_depth=3,
    n_estimators=10000,                                                                    
    subsample=0.8,
    random_state=34
) 

mod.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = mod.predict(X_val)
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_val, predictions))
print("score: {0:,.0f}".format(rmse))
```

Answer (score 8):

There is some good news there is a library [pandas_ml](http://pandas-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xgboost.html) which supports XGBoost. This will probably this streamline the workflow simply.